# Filter files with specific file extensions using regular expression

Tags: regex, unix

I have a file containing a list of filenames:

> esocket.c
>   esocket.h
>   dockwin.cpp
>   dockwin.h
>   makefile
>   getblob
>   .
>   etc...

I am looking for a regular expression (preferably Unix syntax) to do the following:

1. get lines that have .c, cpp and .h files
2. get lines that don't have a file extension.

Comment: meant to say list of filenames (instead of list of files)

Comment: you can always edit your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gawk

```
awk '
{
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
   if ( $i ~ /\.(c|h|cpp)$/){
    print "file with extension: "$i
   }else{
    print "file w/o extension: "$i
   }
 }
}' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
file with extension: esocket.c
file with extension: esocket.h
file with extension: dockwin.cpp
file with extension: dockwin.h
file w/o extension: makefile
file w/o extension: getblob
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 egrep '^[^.]*(\.(cpp|c|h))?$' yourfile
```